# remove column from showing up in document properties

Tags: object-model, office-integration, spfield

Which property in the object model do I use to tell an `SPField` not to show up in the document properties in Office integration? I tried `ShowInEditForm` but that didn't work.

i want my Status column to only be editable by my script.
[image: office integration]

Answer (score 0):

You can just hide that column from your list from library setting.

For detailed steps check:

http://passionatetechie.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-hide-properties-in-document.html